# what's up with this exclamation mark on my lock screen?

Tags: 8.0, lock-screen

There is an exclamation mark next to the city name on my lock screen.

What does that indicate?

[image]

Comment: Getting ready for the MVP Summit as well? :D

Comment: No actually, I'm at the PASS SQL Server Summit!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That symbol means there's a weather alert for your area. It may be a flood, freeze, or some other kind of warning. You'll see the same symbol on the Start tile and in the app.

Answer (score -3):

That means there would be flood or heavy rain on your area

Comment: You may want to expound a little more. E.g. the symbol can mean much more than just flood or heavy rain.